# string (from substr) conversion to unsigned int

Tags: c++, string, std, substr, leveldb

I have a string which actually contains a number and a string, separated by `,`, for instance `"12,fooBar"`.

I would like to put it into separated variables, i.e. the number into `unsigned int myNum` and the string into `std::string myStr`.

I have the following snipped of code:

```
size_t pos1=value.find(',');
std::cout << value.substr(0, pos1) << " and " 
          << (value.substr(0, pos1)).c_str() << std::endl;
```

This yields `12 and 1`. Anything I missed here? What happend to the `2` in the second part?

*Note*: I isolated the problem to this snipped of code. I need `c_str()` to pass it to `atoi` to get the `unsigend int`. Here I don't want to print the second part.

*Update*: I actually get the string from levelDB `Get`. If I put a test string like I put here, it works.

Comment: What you have there ought to work. ([It works for me](http://ideone.com/NoB87).) Please provide a *complete*, *minimal* program that demonstrates the problem. http://sscce.org

Comment: @Rob How can it work? Both his substrs are using the same initial index. He will never get to the string part of his input.

Comment: @Sid, This snippet isn't supposed to get the string part. This snippet of code is supposed to produce `12 and 12`. See OP's note: "I need `c_str()` to pass it to `atoi`".

Comment: @Rob That is for the first part, OP also wants the part after the comma to be in a string. Answer didn't have an explanation, just a snippet...

Comment: Sorry if I didn't made myself clear. But to get the string after the comma is not a problem. I'm just puzzled by the fact that the first part (see snipped) doesn't work as expected. As I pointed out in the edit, the string comes from levelDB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posted code produces the same substring: `value.substr(0, pos1)`. Note that [std::string::substr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) does not modify the object, but returns a new `std::string`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string value ="12,fooBar";
    unsigned int myNum;
    std::string myStr;

    const size_t pos1 = value.find(',');    
    if (std::string::npos != pos1)
    {
        myNum = atoi(value.substr(0, pos1).c_str());
        myStr = value.substr(pos1 + 1);
    }

    std::cout << myNum << " and " 
              << myStr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 12 and fooBar

EDIT:

If the `unsigned int` is the only piece required then the following will work:

```
unsigned int myNum = atoi(value.c_str());
```

as `atoi()` will stop at the first non-digit character (excluding optional leading `-` or `+`), in this case the `,`.

Comment: Thanks for your EDIT. This pointed me to the actual problem. The string I get from levelDB has `""` between `1` and `2` which makes the atoi to fail. Thanks for the hint. Not a solution to my problem, but the answer to my questions ;)

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest C++ style solution to this problem is to use a stringstream.

```
#include <sstream>
// ...
std::string value = "12,fooBar";
unsigned int myNum;
std::string myStr;
std::stringstream myStream(value);
myStream >> myNum;
myStream.ignore();
myStream >> myStr;
```

Comment: Using streams to do the work is the best answer. Though I would have done it in a single statement and tested to make sure the ignored char was a comma.

Comment: I agree that you might want to check the comma. I would also like to put everything on a single row. You are, of course, free to edit the example or leave a suggestion for how it could best be edited.

Something like: 
`char separator;
myStream>>myNum>>separator>>myStr;
if(separator == 'c')
   // ...`

Is that how you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Your second substr should be value.substr(pos1+1,value.length())

Answer (score 0):

One more option is using [std::from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) function from the 17th standard (< charconv > header):

```
int x;
from_chars(&s[i], &s.back(), x); // starting from character at index i parse
                                // the nearest interger till the second char pointer
```

There are different overloads for different types of value x (double etc.).